# Create excel sheets based on values in a column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

First of all I would like to say I'm a complete beginner with VBA.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a column which at times will have different values.Sometimes there might be 2 entries, sometimes, 7, sometimes 11, sometimes 25 etc.

| Levers |
| --- |
| Lever 1 |
| Lever 2 |
| Lever 3 |
| Lever 4 |

I am trying to write a VBA script that will create a number of new sheets, based on how many queries are in the column.

For example, for "Lever 1", I would expect the script to create a new sheet named "Lever 1" with a very specific formatting which you can see in the code below. Aside from these sheets, I would like to create 6 additional sheets for each "Lever" with no specific formatting, titled:
"Lever1Query1",
"Lever1Query2",
"Lever1Query3",
"Lever1Query4",
"Lever1Query5",
"Lever1Keywords"

The same should happen for all the other items in that column, i.e.
"Lever2Query1"
"Lever2Query2" and so on

So far I managed to create the sheets with the names from the column and the formatting I want, but I am struggling to find a way to create the 6 additional sheets for each item in the column.

My code is below:

```
Sub AddSheets()
'Create new sheets
    Dim xRg As Excel.Range
    Dim wSh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wBk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Set wSh = ActiveSheet
    Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
    LastRow = Sheets("I. Search Library").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    hdrs = Array("Supplier", "Category", "Contract ID", "Document Name", "Instance Identifier", "Similarity Score 1", "Extracted Clause 1", "Similarity Score 2", "Extracted Clause 2", "Similarity Score 3", "Extracted Clause 3", "Similarity Score 4", "Extracted Clause 4", "Similarity Score 5", "Extracted Clause 5", "Semantic Indicator", "Keyword 1", "Keyword 2", "Keyword 3", "Keyword 4", "Keyword 5", "Keyword Compliance Indicator", "Lever Score")
    For Each xRg In wSh.Range("B6:B" & LastRow)
        With wBk
            .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = xRg.Value
            
            'create table and name columns
            Set ListObj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("B3:B4"), , xlYes)
            With ListObj
                .ListColumns(1).Name = hdrs(0)
                .ShowTableStyleColumnStripes = False
                .ShowTableStyleRowStripes = False
                For h = 1 To UBound(hdrs)
                    .ListColumns.Add
                    .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).Name = hdrs(h)
                Next h
            End With
            
            'Format Table Header
            With ListObj.HeaderRowRange
                .Interior.Color = RGB(153, 0, 0)
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                .WrapText = True
                .BorderAround _
                 Weight:=xlThick, Color:=RGB(0, 0, 0), LineStyle:=xlContinuous
            End With
                              
            'Instance Identifier Formula
            ActiveSheet.Range("F4:F10000").Formula = "=COUNTIF($E$4:E4,E4)"

            'Format Table Body
            With ListObj.DataBodyRange
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .WrapText = True
                .Rows.AutoFit
                'Format Column Widths
                .Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 43
                .Columns(5).ColumnWidth = 10.3
                .Columns(6).ColumnWidth = 11
                .Columns(7).ColumnWidth = 45
                .Columns(8).ColumnWidth = 11
                .Columns(9).ColumnWidth = 45
                .Columns(10).ColumnWidth = 11
                .Columns(11).ColumnWidth = 45
                .Columns(12).ColumnWidth = 11
                .Columns(13).ColumnWidth = 45
                .Columns(14).ColumnWidth = 11
                .Columns(15).ColumnWidth = 45
                .Columns(16).ColumnWidth = 10.3
                .Columns(17).ColumnWidth = 9.67
                .Columns(18).ColumnWidth = 9.67
                .Columns(19).ColumnWidth = 9.67
                .Columns(20).ColumnWidth = 9.67
                .Columns(21).ColumnWidth = 9.67
                .Columns(22).ColumnWidth = 12.9
                .Columns(23).ColumnWidth = 8.15
                'Format Number Formats
                .Columns(6).Style = "Percent"
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlDot
                .BorderAround _
                 Weight:=xlThick, Color:=RGB(0, 0, 0), LineStyle:=xlContinuous
            End With

            'Group Search Columns
            'Group Column 2-5
            ActiveSheet.Columns("I:P").Group
            'Group Column 3-5
            ActiveSheet.Columns("K:P").Group
            'Group Column 4-5
            ActiveSheet.Columns("M:P").Group
            'Group Column 5
            ActiveSheet.Columns("O:P").Group
            
               
            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
              Debug.Print xRg.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
 
    Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a loop at the end before Next xRg

```vb
    Dim v
    For Each v In Array("Query1", "Query2", "Query3", _
                        "Query4", "Query5", "Keywords")
        .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = xRg.Value & v
    Next
```